Upgrading Mongo java-driver to 5.x
while upgrading mongo-driver to 5.x getting following error while connecting mongo DB.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.internal.TimeoutSettings
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

tried adding following dependencies, did not resolve issue
<dependency>

    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
   
</dependency>

following is connection code
 MongoClients.create( MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(
                    new ConnectionString(uristr))
                    .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                            builder.maxWaitTime(properties.getMaxWaitTime(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .maxConnectionIdleTime(properties.getConnectionIdleTime(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                                    .build());


using mongo driver version 5.1.2 solved problem

Do not know why you get downvotes. That happens rather often with mongo-driver-sync, for example 5.2.1 is also broken this way. 5.1.4 is OK
Bad release engeneering from mongo?
